# Parcel.js - building the app takes too long and plenty of errors: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

Tags: npm, build, parceljs

I am building my app with parcel after I updated the dependecies:

```
 > parcel build index-prod.html --out-file index.html -d build --no-source-maps --no-cache 
/ Building constant.js...EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
- Building constant.js...EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
- Building constant.js...EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
                         EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
| Building constant.js...EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
- Building constant.js...EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
\ Building constant.js...EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
- Building constant.js...EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
\ Building constant.js...EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
- Building constant.js...EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
| Building constant.js...EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
```

Some hundreds of similar rows... eventually finished:

```
 √  Built in 680.21s.
```

As you see it took an eternity to do it. But the build is functional.
Before npm update, it took less than 10s to do it.
What is the problem?

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproduction, perhaps in a github repo? In the meantime, here's one thing to check: there have been similar issues reported in the past ([see here](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/4343#issuecomment-600601086)), and they were caused by a dependency specifier that was pointing to a folder rather than a file. Is there anything like that in `constant.js`?

Comment: Nope, I can't share it, it's not public code.  constant.js is not part of my app or my libraries. It is probably a library required by one of my dependencies. This is the list of recently updated libraries:  "less": "^4.1.1",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.3",
    "parcel-plugin-html-externals": "^0.3.0",
    "parcel-plugin-purifycss": "^1.0.2",
    "postcss": "^8.3.6",
    "postcss-modules": "^4.2.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"

Comment: I see you have `parcel-bundler` - i.e. parcel v1, which is deprecated and not getting updates. You probably want to upgrade to parcel v2 (e.g. remove the `parcel-bundler` line and replace it with `"parcel": "^2.0.1"`). See: https://parceljs.org/getting-started/migration/ Also, it looks like you might be using Vue 2 - in which case you'll want to check out this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-transformer-vue2

Comment: Not a solution to use Parcel v2 as it requires Vue v3. Our project is already developed in Vue 2.x :(

Comment: Did you see the plugin I linked to above? That's for vue 2, not 3.